# How to update vocabulary of pre-trained bert model while doing my own training task?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, bert-language-model

I am now working on a task of predicting masked word using BERT model. Unlike others, the answer needs to be chosen from specific options.

For instance:

```
sentence: "In my daily [MASKED], ..."
options: A.word1 B.word2 C.word3 D.word4
the predict word will be chosen from four given words
```

I use hugging face's BertForMaskedLM to do this task. This model will give me a probability matrix which representing every word's probability of appearing in the [MASK] and I just need to compare the probability of word in options to select the answser.

```
# Predict all tokens
with torch.no_grad():
    predictions = model(tokens_tensor, segments_tensors)
#predicted_index = torch.argmax(predictions[0, masked_index]).item()
#predicted_token = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens([predicted_index])[0]
A = predictions[0, masked_pos][tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids([option1])]
B = predictions[0, masked_pos][tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids([option2])]
C = predictions[0, masked_pos][tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids([option3])]
D = predictions[0, masked_pos][tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids([option4])]
#And then select from ABCD
```

But the problem is:
    If the options are not in the “bert-vocabulary.txt”, the above method is not going to work since the output matrix does not give their probability. The same problem will also appear if the option is not a single word.

Should I update the vocabulary and how to do that? Or how to train the model 
 to add new words on the basis of pre-training?